# Fuzzy Search - having issue with minimumSimilarity

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I am using Lucene.Net ver 3.0.3 and used StandardAnalyzer to create index.

There is a text in my index for which it seems fuzzy search is not working.

- Text in document: CUBAEXPORT
- Text being searched: CUBAEXPOR
- Minimum Similarity: 90%
- Length(CUBAEXPORT) = 10
- Length(CUBAEXPOR) = 9
- Edit Distance = 1
- Similarity = ((10 - 1) / 10 ) * 100 = 90%

In my understanding, `CUBAEXPOR` must have been found at 90% but it is being found at 88%.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's based on the lesser of the length of the search term, and the length of the index term. So, since your search term has a length of 9, 0.88 similarity is the minimum that would allow for one edit distance.

The calculation of the maximum edit distance is something like this:

```
int maxEdits = (int)((1-minSim) * (Math.min(textLength, targetLength)));
```

Also, bear in mind, floating point precision can be an issue here! So, if you were to set minSim = 0.8, and try with a length of 5, you would have 0 maxEdits, because `(1-(float).8)*5` = .99999994, and casting that to an int gets you 0.

Long and short of it, I wouldn't worry overmuch about honing *exactly* where the line is drawn on your fuzzy query.
<sub>(And I'm glad lucene did away with this percentage-based fuzzy similarity tomfoolery)</sub>

Comment: Are you sure about `lesser of the length`? Have you checked the Source Code? I am saying this because length of `CUBAEXPORT` is 10 and the same word with 1 letter missing (difference of 1 out of 10) is 90% the same, it is obvious, ins't it!

Comment: @bjan,- Yes, I do know the source code, and I explained fairly completely how it leads to the behavior you are seeing. "CUBAEXPOR" is nine characters in length, thus the result you are seeing.  Was that unclear? If you don't believe me, it is open source, you could always check it for yourself.

Comment: I cross questioned your answer only because, to me, using minimum length does not make sense. It is very obvious that the two strings are 90% similar then why make it 88%! It is difficult for me to satisfy my customers availing services related with this behavior. Nevertheless, i don't blame you, in fact i am thankful to you to at least let me know it is not me doing the miscalculation (AFAIK).